# Сортировка массива объектов по алфавиту

Tags: java, массивы, сортировка

Есть класс-модель `CountryModel`. У него есть 2 поля: `id` и `title`.

```
public class CountryModel {

    private int id;
    private String title;

    public CountryModel(int id, String title) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
}
```

Я создал список `models` типа `CountryModel`, чтобы вывести на экран список стран.

```
public CountryModelsAdapter() {
    List<CountryModel> models = new ArrayList<>();
    models.add(new CountryModel(TYPE_RUSSIA, "Россия"));
    models.add(new CountryModel(TYPE_GERMANY, "Германия"));
    models.add(new CountryModel(TYPE_FRANCE, "Франция"));
    models.add(new CountryModel(TYPE_ITALY, "Италия"));
    setModels(models);
}
```

Как отсортировать список `models` по полю `title`, чтобы страны на экране показывались в алфавитном порядке (Германия-Италия-Россия-Франция) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Через интерфейс Comparable:

```
public class CountryModel implements Comparable<CountryModel> {
    ...

    public int compareTo(CountryModel other) {
        return getTitle().compareTo(other.getTitle());
    }
}
```

Также можно использовать [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

```
Comparator<CountryModel> countryModelsComparator
  = Comparator.comparing(CountryModel::getTitle);

Collections.sort(models, countryModelsComparator);
```

Comment: А потом где применить метод compareTo()? Сорян за глупый вопрос, в программировании недавно

Comment: @KurtkaBein я невнимательно посмотрел Ваш код, метод compareTo() используется для сортировки массивов Array, Вы используете ArrayList, воспользуйтесь второй частью решения. Comparable  используется для Arrays.sort()

Comment: Благодарствую!!

Comment: одна поправка...ArrayList.sort(....) не сработало, а вот Collections.sort(...) оказалось тем, что надо

Comment: @KurtkaBein спасибо, обновил ответ

Answer (score 2):

Вывод листа, отсортированного по полю типа `String` в алфавитном порядке, на стримах:

**CountryModel:**

```
public class CountryModel {

    . . .

    // вот этот метод сюда добавляем
    public void printTitle() {
        System.out.println(this.title);
    }
}
```

**models** (без изменений):

```
List<CountryModel> models = new ArrayList<>();
models.add(new CountryModel(TYPE_RUSSIA, "Россия"));
models.add(new CountryModel(TYPE_GERMANY, "Германия"));
models.add(new CountryModel(TYPE_FRANCE, "Франция"));
models.add(new CountryModel(TYPE_ITALY, "Италия"));
```

**Stream:**

```
models.stream()
      .sorted(Comparator.comparing(CountryModel::getTitle))
      .forEach(CountryModel::printTitle);

// Германия
// Италия
// Россия
// Франция
```

---

Вывод листа, отсортированного по полю типа `String` в алфавитном порядке, с помощью метода `sort` класса `ArrayList`:

**CountryModel:**

```
public class CountryModel {

    . . .

    // вот этот метод сюда добавляем
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.title;
    }
}
```

**models.sort:**

```
models.sort(Comparator.comparing(CountryModel::getTitle));

System.out.println(models.toString());

// [Германия, Италия, Россия, Франция]
```

---

**Arrays.sort:** (на закуску)

```
CountryModel[] modelsArr = models.toArray(new CountryModel[4]);

Arrays.sort(modelsArr, Comparator.comparing(CountryModel::getTitle));

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(modelsArr));

// [Германия, Италия, Россия, Франция]
```